# Use pyqgis to read postgis database, return layer is always invalid

Tags: pyqt, postgis, qgis, pyqgis

I use pyqgis to read the postgis database, and the returned layer is always invalid. I checked that the structure of the database and the connection string are correct, and I can access it correctly, but pyqgis cannot read it, and all layers are invalid.
my code is

```py
# 
import os
import psycopg2
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'D:\Qgis\bin', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.initQgis()
# 
layer_names = ['btjx']

# 
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection('localhost', '5432', 'eps', 'postgres', '123456')
table = uri.table()
info = uri.connectionInfo()
# 
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'))

# 
layers = []
for layer_name in layer_names:
    uri.setDataSource('public', layer_name, 'the_geom')
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), layer_name, 'postgres')
    if layer.isValid():
        project.addMapLayer(layer)
        layers.append(layer)

# 
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName("MyLayout")
layout = project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)
map_item = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map_item.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5,5, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map_item.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(200,200, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
layout.addLayoutItem(map_item)
map_item.setRect(QRectF(20, 20, 200, 200))
map_item.setLayers(layers)
map_item.zoomToExtent()

# 
scale_bar = QgsLayoutItemScaleBar(layout)
scale_bar.setRect(QRectF(20, 240, 100, 10))
scale_bar.setStyle('Single Box')
scale_bar.setComposerMap(map_item.composerMap())
scale_bar.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers)
layout.addLayoutItem(scale_bar)

# 
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setRect(QRectF(220, 20, 80, 100))
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
legend.setLayerSet([layer.id() for layer in layers])
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)

# 
map_item.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
base_path = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath())
pdf_path = os.path.join(base_path, "output.pdf")
# 
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

I have used psycopg2 to access the database to get the data
The structure of my data table is shown in the figure：[image]

My environment configuration is shown in the figure:
[image]

how can i solve
I wish to read layers and generate a thematic map

Comment: the code points to `the_geom` but the image show the geometry column as being `geom`